# `Rest parameters JSDOC` is not correctly flagged in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsdoc, jsdoc3

Is there something wrong with my code that caused `vscode` to have no correct tip?

```js
/**
 *
 * @param  {...Object} elementList
 * @param  {string} elementList[].type
 */
function add(...elementList) {
    // vscode tip: elementList is (parameter) elementList: any[]
    // expect: elementList is {type: string;}[]
    elementList.map(e => e)
}

// use
add({ type: 'div' }, { type: 'h1' })
```

Comment: Yeah, you actually can't define the type of a property of a parameter like that (`elementList[].type`). As far as I know, in C-style languages (Java, JavaScript/TypeScript, C#, etc.), property are always defined within their parent declaration, e.g. `type ElementList = { type: string }`. Dot notation is just for set/get, not for declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the format `@param {type} parameterName`, e.g.

```js
/**
 * @param {{type: string}[]} elementList
 */
function add(...elementList) {
    elementList.map(e => e)
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^ (parameter) elementList: {type: string}[]
}
```

Alternatively, you can create re-usable type definitions with JSDoc:

```js
// Define an Object type named MyElement with one property (type) of type string.
/**
 * @typedef {Object} MyElement
 * @property {string} type
 */

/**
 * @param {MyElement[]} elementList
 */
function add(...elementList) {
    elementList.map(e => e)
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^ (parameter) elementList: MyElement[]
}
```

Comment: While the code will allow `vscode` to have the correct tip, `jsdoc` does not recognize this syntax. An error occurs when I run ` jsdoc ./index.js `. Jsdoc can't help me generate documentation

Comment: error:
```ERROR: Unable to parse a tag's type expression for source file C:\Users\59426\Desktop\quickly-desktop\r\test.js in line 1 with tag title "param" and text "{{type: string}[]} elementList": Invalid type expression ...
```

Comment: @user15163984 I can verify that my example works in vscode's supported version of jsdoc. I've added an alternative to try, but double-check your syntax first because the first example should work.